# Post from MVC view don't get bind to controller model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view which is displayed on modal window:

```
public ActionResult Details(string test)
{
    var model = _taskService.GetDocumentTasks(test);

    return PartialView("_Details", new CustomViewModel { TaskList = model.ToList() });
}

public class CustomViewModel
{
    public DocumentStatus Status { get; set; }
    public IList<DocumentTask> TaskList { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to loop TaskList in the view and draw form fields like this:

```
@model CustomViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.TaskList.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TaskList[i].TaskId)

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <img src="@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TaskList[i].DocumentPath)">                                
            .. other form items here
        </div>                    
    } 

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

This displays the form fields but when I click the submit button the modal which is sent to the controller is null. I have tried a few different ways of binding it but no success. The model on on the below controller is always null. Any idea how to bind the submitted form details to controller model?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Details(CustomViewModel model) 
    {
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You confirmed the `Details` action is being hit when submitted?

Comment: Yes, it gets hit but the model is always null.

Comment: Have you double checked that the fields are actually being serialised and posted? Use your browser's dev tools to inspect the request that is being generated.

Comment: Yes I can see the fields being posted in Chrome dev tool network tab, they are there but not bound to controller model.

Comment: The code you have shown works fine. Does `DocumentTask` contains properties or just fields (the `DefaultModelBinder` does not bind fields). Also your `<img src="@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TaskList[i].DocumentPath)">` makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

This will work.  I made some minor changes, so please follow this:

Controller/Model:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class TaskService
    {
        public Collection<DocumentTask> GetDocumentTasks(string test)
        {
            Collection<DocumentTask> aCollection = new Collection<DocumentTask>();

            var documentTaska = new DocumentTask { TaskId = "patha", DocumentPath = "~/Images/w.JPG" };
            var documentTaskb = new DocumentTask { TaskId = "pathb", DocumentPath = "~/Images/w.JPG" };
            var documentTaskc = new DocumentTask { TaskId = "pathc", DocumentPath = "~/Images/w.JPG" };
            var documentTaskd = new DocumentTask { TaskId = "pathd", DocumentPath = "~/Images/w.JPG" };
            aCollection.Add(documentTaska);
            aCollection.Add(documentTaskb);
            aCollection.Add(documentTaskc);
            aCollection.Add(documentTaskd);
            return aCollection;
        }
    }

    public class DocumentStatus { }

    public class DocumentTask
    {
        public string TaskId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentPath { get; set; }
        public string UserDataToProveItWorking { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomViewModel
    {
        public DocumentStatus Status { get; set; }
        public IList<DocumentTask> TaskList { get; set; }
    }

    TaskService _taskService = new TaskService();

    public ActionResult Overview()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Details(string test)
    {
        var model = _taskService.GetDocumentTasks(test);

        return PartialView("_Details", new CustomViewModel { TaskList = model.ToList() });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Details(CustomViewModel model)
    {
        return View("Overview");
    }
```

View Overview.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Overview</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        @Html.ActionLink("GetPartialView", "Details", new { test = "aTestValue"})
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Partial View _Detials.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Overview</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        @Html.ActionLink("GetPartialView", "Details", new { test = "aTestValue"})
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```